Can dream interpretations question be asked in this community?
Can dream interpretations question be asked in this community? Along with dream meanings and how they could relate to your life?

Check out this question instead: What is the current “accepted” science behind dream interpretation?

This depends on what you mean:

for your specific dreams to be interpreted, or
whether questions about dream interpretation are allowed.

1. Interpreting specific dreams
No, this is not allowed, as it does not fall under the topics you can ask about on this site.

Don't ask about...

"Self Help" questions which are personal in nature, seeking medical or
professional advice


2. Questions about dream interpretation
This is a more contested issue, exemplified by questions such as "Should we close questions about Freud?", but I believe the current consensus is, yes, as Chris argues:

The problem here is that psychology talks about things in a different way to the likes of neuroscience for example, however it doesn't necessarily mean that the research and development of theories to do with the human psyche are not scientific. It is just that they cannot be measured in the same way as conventional science.

Just make sure to clarify your question restricts itself to adopting methods from this specific field of research, and you should be fine. It will allow those professionals acquainted with that field of research to respond and will fend off others that are not interested in it.

This is a good and well balanced answer.  Asking for an interpretation is definitely not on-topic. As far as psychology is concerned, the rigid idea that dreams can be interpreted is not accepted as nobody can know precisely what they mean.  As pointed out in the linked argument I made, dream analysis is used as a tool, but not rigidly. "Whilst possibly inaccurate, [dream analysis] can give an indication as to possible areas of concern when exploring with your client where problems lie".
